# Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

this statement shows list of friends of user 2 and get count mutual friends of user 1. When I run this, I get following error,

> :Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'where clause'

Query

```
 SELECT  users.user_id,

(SELECT count(a.friendID) FROM
(
  SELECT user_two_id friendID FROM friends  WHERE user_one_id = **users.user_id**
    UNION 
  SELECT user_one_id friendID FROM friends WHERE user_two_id = users.user_id
) AS a 
JOIN  
(
  SELECT user_two_id friendID FROM friends WHERE user_one_id = 1
    UNION 
  SELECT user_one_id friendID FROM friends WHERE user_two_id = 1
) AS b 
ON  a.friendID = b.friendID) as mutual

FROM friends LEFT JOIN  users    ON friends.user_one_id = users.user_id or  friends.user_two_id = users.user_id  WHERE (friends.user_one_id = 2 OR friends.user_two_id = 2)   AND users.user_id != 2
```

Comment: Please provide some sample table data, and the expected output from your query.

Comment: **Pro tip** Indent your SQL query properly. It's MUCH easier to inspect your code to look for trouble. For example, here's a tool to do it. http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: friends table
user_one_id | user_two_id 
1           | 5
1           | 3
2           | 1
2           | 3

users table
user_id
1
2
3
4
5

user 2 friends 1,3  get count mutual friends with user 1  
1 get count mutual 1
3 get count mutual 1

Answer (score 1):

The Inside query

```
 SELECT user_one_id friendID FROM friends WHERE user_two_id = users.user_id
```

Doesnot know what is users.user_id

Answer (score 0):

SELECT user_two_id friendID FROM friends  WHERE user_one_id = **users.user_id**
    UNION 
  SELECT user_one_id friendID FROM friends WHERE user_two_id = **users.user_id**

bold color content should be specific

Comment: If I specific users.user_id with number it is work good but I want to get users.user_id which is select from begin to statemnet

Comment: You should share your tables and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  users.user_id,

(
SELECT COUNT(a.friendID) FROM
        (
            SELECT user_two_id friendID FROM friends  WHERE user_one_id = users.user_id
            LEFT JOIN  users    ON (friends.user_one_id = users.user_id)
            UNION 
            SELECT user_one_id friendID FROM friends WHERE user_two_id = users.user_id
            LEFT JOIN  users    ON (friends.user_one_id = users.user_id)
        ) AS a 
JOIN  
        (
            SELECT user_two_id friendID FROM friends WHERE user_one_id = 1
            UNION 
            SELECT user_one_id friendID FROM friends WHERE user_two_id = 1
        ) AS b 
ON  a.friendID = b.friendID
) AS mutual

FROM friends 
LEFT JOIN  users  ON friends.user_one_id = users.user_id OR  friends.user_two_id = users.user_id  
WHERE (friends.user_one_id = 2 OR friends.user_two_id = 2)   AND users.user_id != 2
```

Comment: simple correct in your statement  : LEFT JOIN  users    ON (friends.user_one_id = users.user_id)  is before where not after it , after correct it work but it get same mutual count for all users_id , but I want to check every user_id mutual count with user 1